# Select from database in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I can't get clean results from database,

```
module PagesHelper
    def list
        wishes = WishList.select("content").where("user_id = #{@user.id}")      
        wishes.each do |wish|                                                   
            puts wish.fetch_hash                                                
        end                                                                     
    end                                                                         
end
```

results for user with id 6:

```
[#<WishList content: "test3">, #<WishList content: "test4">, #<WishList content: "test5">]
```

but i want to get list like:
test3, test4, test5 without flood, how i can get it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, **never ever ever interpolate values into `where`**. This can lead to SQL injection of parameters. For example, this is bad:

```
WishList.select("content").where("user_id = #{@user.id}")
```

And this is OK:

```
WishList.select("content").where(:user_id => @user.id)
```

This will *automatically* escape the `@user.id` portion of the query, which there isn't really a need for in in this query, but imagine you were doing something like this:

```
User.select("email, password").where("admin = #{params[:admin]}")
```

Then anybody could pass through any value in `params[:admin]` they want.

So.

---

Anyway, access it through an association:

```
wishes = @user.wishlist.select("content")
```

Then as Carl Lazlo recommended:

```
wishes.map(&:content)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
wishes.each do |wish|                                                   
  puts wish.fetch_hash                                                
end
```

Do:

```
wishes.map(&:content)
```